# Casey Novak's lie and departure

Tags: plot-explanation, law-and-order-svu

In [Law & Order: SVU](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0203259/), what was the 'lie' that Casey Novak told to a judge that led to her being fired/disbarred/imprisoned? What exactly was the consequence? How did it come out that she had lied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She basically violates due process by breaking the Brady rules, which are rules governing the disclosure of all information to all parties (Such as not prosecuting a witness in exchange for testimony). She does this to convict a cop rapist.

Initially she is told that she is facing either censure or being disbarred, and when she left the show they settled on disbarred. This is contradicted, however, a few seasons later when she returns to the show and it was reduced to a censure.

Comment: What was the evidence/information that she didn't disclose?  Do they ever explain why it was reduced?

Comment: @WayneWeibel Not that I know of, and I don't remember the specifics, I'd have to go watch the episode again. I suspect that it was changed for much the same reason that people miraculously spring back to life in soap operas, they needed the story arc.